# How websites/webURL's being stopped visiting by web crawler and bots?

Tags: web-crawler, user-agent, robots.txt

I have one website and many times this websites is visited by web crawlers bots. I want to get rid off it. Plz suggest me possible way of solutions to avoid my websites being accessed by bots.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If your site is public, your options are limited.  Here are a few suggestions:

- The most obvious: password-protect your site.   This may not be the most practical for a public site but is guaranteed to work.
- Define robots.txt rules for your site.  Crawlers are not obligated to follow these rules but friendly ones (hopefully most of them) usually honor the robots.txt.
- If those bots annoy you because they are not playing nice with your site (like hitting it too fast), there is also the option of detecting and blocking their IP.  This will only work as long as they do not start to crawl from a different IP address.
- Hopefully the web crawler bots hitting your site identify themselves properly via distinct HTTP request User-Agent values.  You can block your page for unwanted user-agents.  The robots.txt can do that, but here I am talking about having the webserver detect it and not rendering the page at all or return an error.

You did not say why you wanted to block them.  The answer to this may influence the approach you take.  For instance, if you want to keep sensitive data to a selected group of people, password-protection is probably the best way to go instead of trying to hunt bots forever.  If it's a site performance concern, think of a more powerful host for your site.  Hopefully one or a mix of the above suggestions will do the job for you.

Comment: Answering your reply in 2-3 messages (due to reply is too long)

Comment: Regard of the site, it is under one application and it is also my university project,

First i'll start with your suggestions,

1. I can not add password because my app doesn't allow me to give password authentication.

2. About robot.txt rules, only some good crawlers/bots will obey rules. Bad robots deny this rule very easily.

3. Site is continuously hitting by bots too.
About blocking IP i like to ask what happen when bot will started using proxy ip address, also ip changes on regular basic according to facts and analysis.

Comment: 4. Talking about user agents we can rely somewhat on userAgents but can't totally.IE explore allow us to create our own defined user agent while requesting web page.

My web app is social app it is regulary posts comments and page links on social media then i check the referral traffic from the social media,from there i get bot/crawler hit to my app and that i want to stop. 
impact page load counts increases drastically.

According to this situation still is there any solution/logic do you have to apply over.

Thanks.

Comment: Getting hosted on a more capable server is not an option for you? Unless we are talking about Denial Of Service attacks, your app should be able to handle bots without issues.  If you can identify the bots by IP, check who owns that IP and verify with them if you can be excluded from their crawl.

Also If it is YOUR app, why can't you add authentication?  It does not have to be browser authentication, it can be form-based.  

If the issue is with the bots reading your content, you can decide to render it using javascript tricks with Ajax so bots have a hard time to get to your content.

Comment: Also, unless I misread, I don't see an explanation WHY you want to block them.  If it is just because of the noise it generates on your stats, you can check with your social media site if those can be excluded, or apply some of my suggestions in y first reply and you'll get rid of most of them (if not all).

Comment: One last idea: does not your University have an IntrAnet?  If you are worried about public access, that would be a better place to put your app. You can also look at setting up firewall rules or a VPN so that only specific people/IPs can access your site.  If you can't not do any of these options at your university, consider hosting on AWS or equivalent cloud service (they have a free tier). You will be less limited.  If you can't do that either, well, the issue is no longer a technical one! ;-)  Talk to your university tech admin or superiors to get what you need for your project. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Pascal for your comment and time!